# How to convert OpenVZ OS template to bootable image file?

Tags: debian, virtualization, openvz, qemu

My question is how to convert a pre-created OpenVZ OS template which are in tar.gz format (such as  [these](http://wiki.openvz.org/Download/template/precreated)) to an image file in order to be able boot it with other virtualization solutions such as QEMU or VirtualBox.

In order to achieve this, I made an empty image file, I partitioned it, and made two partition, a primary partition and a extended partition for swap. I made the first partition ext3 (0x83) and the other one swap (0x82). Then I made the first one bootable, and copied the content of tar.gz to the first partition. But when I try to boot, it hangs at the first stage of booting.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An OpenVZ template lacks a number of important files needed to boot a non-container based guest, for example it lacks a kernel and a bootloader (GRUB). Actually, a whole `/boot` directory is missing on the OpenVZ template, so you need to get it somewhere. A way to go is to install a very minimal setup of a distribution you need using "normal" installation procedure such as CD or network-based installation and copy `/boot` to your OpenVZ-converted image using a LiveCD then. You will need to set up GRUB manually after that using the same LiveCD. Another approach is to set up a minimal set of packages using normal install and rsync everything from an OpenVZ template to your new image then.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'm trying to test this, and I'll report back, is it enough just to replace /boot directory from the minimal installation ?

Comment: It seems it's more complicated than just copying the boot folder. It needs to be partitioned specifically for CentOS(as I need it), which should have Volume-Group and Logical Volumes, and also we nee a partition for /boot folder, /dev folder should be created for tar.gz template,  /etc/fstab and /etc/resolv.conf and other network config files should be edited manually and then grub and kernel should be installed manually, there may be other stuff I'm not aware of, but since I didn't find a complete solution or a step by step procedure, I gave up for now :(

Comment: Yes, you are right, copying `/boot` folder is not enough. I think copying `/boot` and installing GRUB using a LiveCD will lead you to a bootable system, but you will need to configure the network, etc as you pointed out.